# Security concern with user entered values in inappbrowser

Tags: android

I was shopping in an android app and at the time of payment it gave me multiple options like credit card, internet banking etc.
I selected internet banking and it opened up an inappbrowser and redirected to my bank login page.
For sure I know app and my bank domain names are different.
Since this page is running inside an app, Is there a possibility that app can read my login details from inappbrowser?

Comment: What's the question? You should never trust these apps because you are vulnerable to phishing attacks.

Comment: Please remove in-app-purchase tag as it is not related to it.

Comment: Why not just broadcasting an Intent and let the user choose where to open the link...what you described sounds very fishy.